# Script to be executed from terminal cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, terminal

I want to invoke webservices from local machine. I have created a shell script from the server. Now I want to invoke it from the local machine.

I am running the following commands in my cmd in terminal:

1.:

```
    cd C:\Users\xx\Desktop\ODTU\UCM\generic
    java -classpath %CLASSPATH%;oracle.ucm.fa_genericclient_11.1.1.jar oracle.ucm.idcws.client.UploadTool --url=https://hdeo-xx.oracle.com/idcws/GenericSoapPort --policy=oracle/wss_username_token_over_ssl_client_policy --primaryFile=Image.zip --dDocName=UCM_09277231 --dDocTitle=Image.zip --dSecurityGroup=FAFUsionImportExport --dDocAccount="hcm$/dataloader$/import$" --username=xx.user --password=Oracle100 --socketTimeout=20 –verbose
```

2.:

```
    java -classpath -Dhttps.proxyHost="xx.18.92.xx" -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -cp "C:/Users/sreelsre/Desktop/ODTU/UCM/generic/dataLoaderProxy.jar";"C:\Users\sreelsre\Desktop\ODTU\UCM\generic" DataLoaderServiceSoapHttpPortClient UCM_09277231
```

I want this to be executed from my local machine that is a terminal like we run the shell script from server. Is there any command for that?

Also how do we handle parameters? For example in shell script if we want to pass a parameter we write:

```
sh filename.sh  param1 param2
```

I have created a .bat file for the same but it has few extra characters like

```
∩╗┐@echo off
```

how do i add parameters to this .bat file?

Comment: Almost the same as shell, but inside you .bat recover each parameter with %1 %2 ...

Comment: The three (3) funny looking characters at the beginning of your .bat script is a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark). If you are using Windows Notepad, select  `Encoding:  ANSI` in the File > Save As dialog box.